# Add this CSS to Codeigniter Pagination

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I'm trying to convert this HTML and implement this to Codeigniter's Pagination.
I am really stuck. I can't figure this out.

The HTML code: (This code is based on the css and it works perfectly fine. It is like a pagination template)

```
<div class="pagination pagination-sample">
                        <!-- Minimal pagination variant -->
                        <a class="pagination__prev" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                        <div class="pagination__block">
                            <a class="pagination__item" href="#">1</a>
                            <a class="pagination__item" href="#">2</a>
                            <a class="pagination__item mobile-small active-page" href="#">3</a>
                            <a class="pagination__item mobile-large" href="#">4</a>
                            <a class="pagination__item mobile-large" href="#">5</a>
                        </div>
                        <a class="pagination__next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
    </div>
```

What I have so far:

```
  $uid = $this->session->userdata('uid'); //added on sat , feb 28

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/profile/entries';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('entry')->num_rows();
    $this->db->where('uid', $uid);
    $this->db->order_by("time", "desc"); 
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-sample">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<a class="pagination__next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</i></a>';

    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<a class="pagination__prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</i></a>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a class="pagination__item mobile-small active-page" ';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['records'] = $this->db->get('dayone_entries', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));
    $this->pagination->create_links();
```

My view file

```
    <?php include "includes/settings.php" ?>

<html>
    <body>
<div class="container">

        <h3 class="block-title block-title--simple"> Your <?php echo $site_title ?> Entries </h3>

<div class="devider-brand "></div>

         <?php echo $this->table->generate($records); ?>
        <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>



        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Generally you also want to use an unordered list, most of the CSS vendors use lists, such as bootstrap,foundation

Comment: Sorry if that didn't make sense. I already have CSS which is properly set up. I made a theme for my site. I have all the css in one huge style.css file.
So basically, I want to customize the pagination links to my theme. That's the HTML code to a proper pagination funtion for my theme. I just wanna include it in php. Thanks.

Comment: What you have should work, along with $config['next_tag_open'] and $config['prev_tag_open'] 
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: I'm using that for this but it still doesn't work. Like the previous button will show up with the icon and everything but it won't do anything if I click it.

Comment: Are you creating the markup(html) yourself? If so you need to remove it. $this->pagination->create_links() will create the markup for you, with the correct links based on the $config

Comment: I added `$this->pagination->create_links();` but it still doesn't work. It shows the next and previous arrows but nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: You will need to provide your controller/model code for me to get a better understanding of the code state.

Comment: I have updated with more information. Thank you very much!

Comment: Its a big job to fix, you need to tell the database what offsets and limits to use, as well as some other configuration you are missing.  I will help you get up and running but it may take me some time to write a correct answer. I would encourage you to look at the codeigniter docs, most notably MVC in the meantime.

Comment: Hey @Philip Thanks for helping with this. I have fixed it.

I have one final problem. I'm only showing the data in the table if the data is created by the user. That's why I have the ` $this->db->where('uid', $uid);` But one problem. If I only limit 5 to see in the table, and the user only has 5 rows(data), but in the database, there are 100+ because other memebers also created it, the pagination will say something like: << < 1 2 3 4 5 > >> Even though it doesn't need to show that much because the user only has 5 rows. Is there a way to fix this issue, where the user will see too many numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use div's, you need to use `for each` instead of whatever else you are using.